# Geoserver WMS Circle SLD style return incomplete Circle with higher zoom levels

Tags: geoserver, wms

I'm using [OpenGeo Suite Boundless](http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/) v2.6

I created a SLD style for a points layer and create 2 rules:

- Rule to draw a graphics icon from png file.
- Rule to draw a circle with radius(size) from db table using (OGC Attribute) value in meters.

I use the following code to load the layer in OL3:

```
    var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS ({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms',
    params: {'TILED': true, VERSION:'1.3.0',
       'LAYERS': 'myds:antenna',
    },
    serverType: 'geoserver'
});

new ol.layer.Tile({
         id:'Message',
         title: 'Antennas',
         visible: true ,
         source:wmsSource
     });
```

The layer loaded correctly on the map in some lower zoom levels (0-10) if i zoomed in to more levels down (11-17) the circle shape is trimmed by the tiles like the image below:

[image: InComplete circle in WMS layer]

The strange thing when i set the 2nd rule in the SLD that to get a fixed radius value like (2000) meters - Not from db table -, it draw a complete circle in all zoom levels, but i need to set a different radius for each circle.

I tried many solutions to avoid this error by changing the metatiling factors to be 100x100 instead of 4x4 and change the Gutter to be 100px, it solve the problem but affect the loading speed badly.

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

After applying [iant](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/79/iant) suggestion by posting a bug to [Geoserver](http://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS) in the following link [Geoserver Issue](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-7171)

but the first answer was:

> This is not a bug, GeoServer cannot predict how large the circle will
> be since it's attribute dependent.  You have to setup manually a
> rendering buffer large enough to care for all your needs in the layer
> configuration:
> http://docs.geoserver.org/2.7.1/user/webadmin/data/layers.html

Another answer is using  **ol.source.ImageWMS`** instead of using **`ol.source.TileWMS`** which will return the WMS response in ONE Single Image not tiled image so that the circles will not be trimmed like the previously attached image.

I tried this answer and the incomplete circle disappeared and the result are complete circles with the selected radius from the DB attribute.

So the Conclusion is :

- Use **`ol.source.ImageWMS`** if you want to load the WMS response in a single tile image - not tiled images -.